# suddenly windows 7 asks for username and password

Tags: windows-7, passwords, virus, logging, malware

I think my computer has been infected with a kind of virus or malware.
Yesterday I locked my windows and went out of house, at return as I tried to use it again it asked for a password!
(I'm pretty sure that I didn't set it). So I tried some passwords but none of them worked. So I put a windows 7 installation disk into my computer and did some none sense things. Finally I restarted my computer and it offered to repair the windows, I chose this option and it logged me in finally (without any user/pass required). Obviously I thought that was trivial and after a while I locked it again and now it asks me for password again!

Fortunately I've created another user with administrator privileges but I cannot reset the (unset!!!) password of the main account, It says "Access is denied".

Interestingly as I restarted the computer and wanted to log in with my new account it asked me for both username and password!!!! (I've never seen such a thing), even the picture of the account was missing, but fortunately I remembered them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just as a precaution, try running `sfc /scannow` in a command prompt to check for corrupted system files.

Comment: @Moses- Thanks I'll do it. But for now I'm scanning the computer with anti virus and so far it's found 18 infections in the registry.

Comment: Don't forget to scan for malware too. Make sure the system is completely clean before running `SFC /scannow`.